# Find two lines in file that are the same

Tags: algorithm, search

I was asked this question in an Amazon interview.

You have a file with many lines but two of the lines are the same.  Find those two lines.  I gave the obvious answer that ran in N^2 time.  I then came up with an answer that used a hash table, but they didn't like that answer either because they say it wouldn't work if the file was in the gigabytes.  Another answer I came up with was instead of storing the hash result in memory, create a file with the same name as the hash value, and store the lines with the same same hash value in the file.  Either they couldn't understand my solution or they didn't like it.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: For Linux it is easy `sort <filename> | uniq -c | grep '^2 '`

Comment: Ok, let me look at the other solutions, but wouldn't this slurp the file into memory?

Comment: @JohnSmith: GNU `sort` knows how to do an external sort when the data doesn't fit in memory (http://vkundeti.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/tech-algorithmic-details-of-unix-sort.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two essential classes of solutions to this problem:

1. **Probabilistic in-memory solutions.**  You can try to solve this problem by storing a summary of the lines of the file in main memory.  You can then do computations in main memory to identify possible duplicates, then check each possible duplicate by looking back on disk.  These solutions are probably the best, since they have low memory usage, high efficiency, and mimize disk accesses.  Solutions in this category include

   1. Compute a hash of each line of the file, then store the hashes.  Any lines that have a hash collision represent one possible pair of lines that might collide, and just those lines can be explored.
   2. Use a Bloom Filter to store all the lines of the file, then check only pairs that collide in the Bloom Filter.  This is essentially a variation of (1) that is more space-efficient.
2. **Deterministic on-disk solutions**.  You can try to do computations with the entire data set on-disk, using main memory as temporary scratch space.  This would let you get exact answers without having to hold the whole file in memory, but would probably be slower unless you were doing some later processing and could benefit from restructuring the data.  Solutions in this category include

   1. Use an external sorting algorithm (external quicksort, external radix sort, etc.) to sort the file, then linear search it for a pair of duplicate elements.
   2. Build an on-disk data structure like a B-tree holding all of the strings, then query the B-tree.  This takes a lot of preprocessing time, but makes future operations on the file a lot faster.
   3. Put everything in a database and query the database.

Hope this helps!

Comment: External sort seems like the most straightforward solution.  One optimization is that while you are sorting, you could determine the duplicates as you go along and merge the chunks, thus potentially having to sort the entire file.

Comment: I'll mark this as the correct answer because it has many correct answers, answers where I learned something new, especially external sort and Bloom Filters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Bloom filter:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter

Then you can detect (with few false positives) lines that are repeated and store then in memory, and then go through the file once again.

Two passes through the file, very little memory usage, beautiful

Comment: The second pass does not have to be sequential isn't it? It can be done with a bunch of fseek() calls if we store the location of each line along with the hash I believe.

Comment: No, the point is that if you store locations, you are storing a lot more than the couple of bits per entry that Bloom filters store.

Comment: I see, I have misunderstood the Bloom filter. Thanks!

Comment: After reading about Bloom filters, here's how I think it will work:
(1) Build and maintain the bitmap for each line.
(2) If for a line, if all the bits are already in the vector, add the line to a list in memory.  Save that for later, because that indicates the line is probably already there before.
(3) After you're done with one pass of the file, go through the list in memory and determine which lines are duplicates.

Comment: Correct, exactly like that.

Answer (score 0):

Run through the lines and compute lengths of each line. You'll end up with something like:

```
0: 4  
1: 6  
2: 10  
3: 4  
....
```

Compare only thoose lines that have the same length. Working with such index can be further optimized (e.g. not storing everything in a flat array, but in some kind of tree, or whatever).

By the way, you second idea with file might be declined due to performance reasons. It's generally bad idea to have frequent random IO with hard disk: try to store as much as you can in memory.

Comment: I think this is an elegant solution, but they might complain that you're having to use extra memory.  Of course, if the file has many lines with the same size, you'll have a problem.